# Java Class Not Found Exception but its in the same src folder

Tags: java, class

My code is something like

```
ArrayList<someClassIMade> c=new ArrayList<someClassIMade>();
c.add(new someClassIMade(blah,blah))
```

But for some reason in the add line I get a class not found exception! The someClassIMade class is in the same src folder as the main class so I'm baffled. I literally do this *all the freakin time* why is it not working all of a sudden? I checked my run configuration and yes the src folder is there. The program runs and all, I only see the exception when I went to debug to see why the add line wasn't working and voila class not found. I'm rambling, help?

EDIT:
More code to make this a little clearer
Here is the someClassIMade

```
public tuples{
    private int start;
private int end;
private int[] tuple=new int[2];
public int getStart() {
    return start;
}
public void setStart(int start) {
    this.start = start;
}
public int getEnd() {
    return end;
}
public void setEnd(int end) {
    this.end = end;
}
public int[] getTuple() {
    return tuple;
}
public void setTuple(int[] tuple) {
    this.tuple = tuple;
}
public tuples(int start,int end){
    this.start=start;
    this.end=end;
    tuple[0]=start;tuple[1]=end;

}
```

}
and the code I posted earlier is the first time when it shows up in the class I'm trying to use it in and that's where the error occurs. They are both in the (default package) and I am using only Java native libraries. Hope that clears things up

Comment: I assume that not only is the source there, but you're compiling both of them successfully to class files?

Comment: can you paste the exception you are getting ?

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Comment: You might want to check your classpath too: `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`. You can change it using the `-cp`/`-classpath` flag when calling `java`. Java will only load class files that reside inside one of these paths (and being in the right package folders).

Comment: No, paste the entire exception including the message and the stack trace. We can read what you wrote before.

Comment: Please show more code to clarify this.

Comment: That's literally all it says, wasn't being a dick. The message and the stack trace are both listed as null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are using eclipse? If yes, please do a project clean and select build automatically. I think the classes are not getting build.

Comment: I hope there is no compilation error in the project as in that case eclipse wont build the java to .class..can you go and check the bin folder of our project for the existence of someclass.class file.. if .class is there then try restarting eclipse..also check the buildpath..Right click proj->buildpath->sources ->your source folder should be listed here..otherwise build process will ignore files inside this source folder..i hope its normal java project

Comment: I checked the build path and the bin folders before I came here, but I didn't try restarting. It worked somewhat, the error no longer stops that section of code but it does still pop up leading me to think that I may have some deeper issue with the order of my code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the constructor of `someClassIMade` is private.