# ClassNotFoundException even though the class is properly defined (I think)

Tags: java, eclipse, class, classnotfoundexception

There is a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487549/java-class-not-found-exception-but-its-in-the-same-src-folder) but the answer seems to have never been found. I have tried a clean and am still getting a `ClassNotFoundException`.

So what is happening, like in the linked question, I call the add function in `ArrayList<Player>` and it proceeds to tell me that it cannot find the Player class, even though it is there and I have imported it correctly (since it can  make use of the other class in that path. I will try and post as much code as I think necessary.

au.thewebeditor.scoreboard.apps.AccessMySQL.java

```
package au.thewebeditor.scoreboard.apps;

import java.sql.*;

import au.thewebeditor.scoreboard.defs.*;

public class AccessMySQL {
    private static Connection connection = null;
    private static Statement statement = null;
    private static PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    private static ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public static void readData() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://HOSTNAME/socmedi2_rce?user=socmedi2_sam&password=abc123");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM scores WHERE hasChanged > 0");
            writeResultSet(resultSet);
            //resetHasChanged();
        } catch (SQLException exc) {
            throw exc;
        } finally {
            close();
        }
    }   
    private static void writeResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
            String name = resultSet.getString("name");
            int score = resultSet.getInt("score");
            int lastScore = resultSet.getInt("lastScore");
            if (lastScore == 0){
                Scoreboard.addScore(id, name, score);
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < Scoreboard.getLength(); i++){
                    if (Scoreboard.getID(i) == id){
                        Scoreboard.updateScore(i, score);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Scoreboard.sortScoreboard();
    }
    private static void resetHasChanged() throws SQLException{
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE scoreboard.scores SET hasChanged = 0 WHERE hasChanged > 0");
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    }
    private static void close() {
        try {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                resultSet.close();
            }

            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //DO NOTHING???
        }
    }
}
```

---

au.thewebeditor.scoreboard.apps.Scorboard.java

```
package au.thewebeditor.scoreboard.apps;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import au.thewebeditor.scoreboard.defs.*;

public class Scoreboard extends JWindow {
    static Config configuration = new Config();
    private static ArrayList<Player> scores = new ArrayList<Player>(20);
    private static JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel();
    private static JLabel subtitleLabel = new JLabel();
    private static JLabel[] positionLabel = new JLabel[configuration.getListLength()];
    private static JLabel[] nameLabel = new JLabel[configuration.getListLength()];
    private static JLabel[] scoreLabel = new JLabel[configuration.getListLength()];
    private static JLabel[] changeLabel = new JLabel[configuration.getListLength()];
    private static JLabel[] arrowLabel = new JLabel[configuration.getListLength()];

    public Scoreboard(){
        //Set to full screen
        this.setBounds(0, 0, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height);
        updateLabels(); //Set value of headings
        updateScores();
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        GridBagLayout mainLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout(mainLayout);//Grid size is 5 across: Position, name, $value, change, arrow
        //TITLE LABEL
        GridBagConstraints constraint = AutoConstraint.buildConstraint(new AutoConstraint(0, 0, 5, 1, 100, 0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER));
        mainLayout.setConstraints(titleLabel, constraint);
        add(titleLabel);
        //SUBTITLE LABEL
        constraint = AutoConstraint.buildConstraint(new AutoConstraint(0, 1, 5, 1, 100, 0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER));
        mainLayout.setConstraints(subtitleLabel, constraint);
        add(subtitleLabel);
        //SCOREBOARD
        for (int i = 0; i < configuration.getListLength(); i++){
            if (nameLabel[i].getText() == ""){
                //Print empty line
                constraint = AutoConstraint.buildConstraint(new AutoConstraint(1, i + 2, 5, 1, 100, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST));
                mainLayout.setConstraints(nameLabel[i], constraint);
                add(nameLabel[i]);
            } else {
                add(arrowLabel[i]);
                //ChangeLabel
                constraint = AutoConstraint.buildConstraint(new AutoConstraint(0, i + 2, 1, 1, 20, 1, GridBagConstraints.EAST));
                mainLayout.setConstraints(changeLabel[i], constraint);
                add(changeLabel[i]);
                //ArrowLabel
                constraint = AutoConstraint.buildConstraint(new AutoConstraint(1, i + 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST));
                mainLayout.setConstraints(arrowLabel[i], constraint);
                add(arrowLabel[i]);
                //PositionLabel
                constraint = AutoConstraint.buildConstraint(new AutoConstraint(2, i + 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, GridBagConstraints.EAST));
                mainLayout.setConstraints(positionLabel[i], constraint);
                add(positionLabel[i]);
                //NameLabel
                constraint = AutoConstraint.buildConstraint(new AutoConstraint(3, i + 2, 1, 1, 40, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST));
                mainLayout.setConstraints(nameLabel[i], constraint);
                add(nameLabel[i]);
                //ScoreLabel
                constraint = AutoConstraint.buildConstraint(new AutoConstraint(4, i + 2, 1, 1, 30, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST));
                mainLayout.setConstraints(scoreLabel[i], constraint);
                add(scoreLabel[i]);
            }
        }
        this.setBounds(0, 0, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void updateLabels() {//Updates heading labels
        titleLabel.setText(configuration.getTitle());
        subtitleLabel.setText(configuration.getSubtitle());
        titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, (int)(42*configuration.getFontAdjust())));
        subtitleLabel.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, (int)(32*configuration.getFontAdjust())));
    }
    public static void updateScores() {//Updates scoreboard labels
        try {
            AccessMySQL.readData();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            String[] options = {"Retry", "Exit"};
            int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "MySQL database failed to load. Error code: " + Integer.toString(e.getErrorCode()) + ".\n" + e.getMessage(), "MySQL Error", 0, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null, options, options[1]);
            if (response == 1 || response == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION)
                Runtime.getRuntime().exit(ERROR);
            else
                Program.redrawScoreboard();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hard Coded Failure, Contact Mowgli for Support.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exit(ERROR);
        }
        int change = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < configuration.getListLength(); i++){
            try {
                positionLabel[i] = new JLabel(Integer.toString(i + 1) + ". ");
                positionLabel[i].setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, (int)(24*configuration.getFontAdjust())));
                nameLabel[i] = new JLabel(scores.get(i).getName());
                nameLabel[i].setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, (int)(24*configuration.getFontAdjust())));
                scoreLabel[i] = new JLabel("$" + Integer.toString(scores.get(i).getScore()));
                scoreLabel[i].setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, (int)(24*configuration.getFontAdjust())));
                change = scores.get(i).getLastPosition() - i - 1;
                changeLabel[i] = new JLabel();
                changeLabel[i].setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, (int)(24*configuration.getFontAdjust())));
                if (scores.get(i).getLastPosition() == 0){
                    changeLabel[i].setText("NEW! ");
                    changeLabel[i].setForeground(Color.yellow);
                    arrowLabel[i] = new JLabel(" " + Character.toString((char)171));
                    arrowLabel[i].setForeground(Color.yellow);
                } else if (change > 0){
                    changeLabel[i].setText("+" + Integer.toString(change) + " ");
                    changeLabel[i].setForeground(Color.green);
                    arrowLabel[i] = new JLabel(" " + Character.toString((char)233));
                    arrowLabel[i].setForeground(Color.green);
                } else if (change < 0){
                    changeLabel[i].setText(Integer.toString(change) + " ");
                    changeLabel[i].setForeground(Color.red);
                    arrowLabel[i] = new JLabel(" " + Character.toString((char)234));
                    arrowLabel[i].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else {
                    changeLabel[i].setText(Character.toString((char)177)+"0 ");
                    changeLabel[i].setForeground(Color.gray);
                    arrowLabel[i] = new JLabel(" " + Character.toString((char)108));
                    arrowLabel[i].setForeground(Color.gray);
                }
                scores.get(i).setLastPosition(i+1); //Sets last position before sort is called.
                arrowLabel[i].setFont(new Font("Wingdings", Font.PLAIN, (int)(24*configuration.getFontAdjust())));
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                nameLabel[i] = new JLabel("");
            }
        }
    }
        public static void addScore(int id, String name, int score){//Adds new score to scores ArrayList
            scores.add(new Player(id, name, score, 0));
        }
    public static void updateScore(int index, int score){//Updates score value, does not rearrange or assign lastPosition or position
        scores.get(index).setScore(score);
    }
    public static int getLength(){//Returns the current length of the scoreboard
        return scores.size();
    }
    public static int getID(int index){//takes the ArrayList index value and returns the ID value
        return scores.get(index).getID();
    }
    public static void sortScoreboard(){//Sorts scoreboard DESC
        Collections.sort(scores);
    }
}
```

---

au.thewebeditor.scoreboard.apps.Program.java

```
package au.thewebeditor.scoreboard.apps;

   public class Program {
    private static Scoreboard sb;
    private static ConfigPanel cp;

public Program(){
    sb = new Scoreboard();
    cp = new ConfigPanel();
}

public static void redrawScoreboard() throws NullPointerException{
    try{
        sb.dispose();
    } catch (NullPointerException e){
        //DO NOTHING
    }
    sb = new Scoreboard();
    cp.toFront();
}

public static void showConfig(){
    cp.setVisible(true);
    cp.toFront();
}

public static void main(String[] arguments){
    new Program();
}
}
```

I hope this is enough informmation to spot the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Including proper coding habits, as I am new to Java.

Comment: I dnt see you importing `Player` class in `Scoreboard`. Did you import it?

Comment: What Class caused the ClassNotFound exception ???

Comment: @BruceMartin `"..tell me that it cannot find the Player class..."`

Comment: @Bill

Line 10:
`import au.thewebeditor.scoreboard.defs.*;`

This should import it, no?

@Bruce I believe the Player class causes the exception, as the debugger tells me that it cannot find Player in au.thewebeditor.scoreboard.defs

Comment: @user1306069 What editor are you using, and how are you compiling it?

Comment: @user1306069 I missed that import, sorry. Yes, that should be way to import `player` in `scoreboard`.

Comment: Where does it throw the exception? How do you run this code? `main` method or server (or other)?

Comment: @Bill I am using Eclipse, using Build Automatically. How do I know how I am compiling it, Eclipse handles that for me =)

Comment: @acdcjunior It throws it at `scores.add(new Player(...));` The program is run from a `main` method in au.thewebeditor.scoreboard.apps.Program.java

Comment: @user1306069 As long as you dnt see any `errors`, Eclipse is fine in compiling the code. So, can you share your `program.java` at least the imports and other related code.

Comment: So it seems your build path (compilation classpath) is different than your running classpath. How do you run the code?

Comment: @acdcjunior I press the RUN or DEBUG button on Eclipse. It takes care of the rest.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace? Something doesn't smell right here; when Java fails to load a class referred to by a `new` expression, it should throw a `NoClassDefFoundError`, not a `ClassNotFoundException`. The latter should only happen when you try to load a class reflectively.

Comment: @ruakh how do I retrieve the full stacktrace?

Comment: In your catch use `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Eclipse corrects me saying that it's an unreachable catch block. I tried to place the try/catch on addScore: `public static void addScore(...) throws ClassNotFoundException {`

Comment: @MowgliB: O.K., let's try a different tack . . . you say that you get a `ClassNotFoundException`. How did you determine that that's what you get? What are you actually seeing?

Comment: @ruakh: I used the debug tool and stepped through my code until I got to `scores.add()`, it tells me I have a `ClassNotFoundException(Throwable).<init>(String, Throwable) line 286` I realised I could copy the stack by right-clicking on the debug view. `ClassNotFoundException(Exception).<init>(String, Throwable) line: not available` , `ClassNotFoundException(ReflectiveOperationException).<init>(String, Throwable) line: not available` and `ClassNotFoundException.<init>(String) line: not available` does any of this help?

Comment: @MowgliB: It tells me that the debug tool is having a problem. It doesn't tell me very much about your actual problem. :-/

Comment: @ruakh: Is there any other information I can get from the debug tool? Thanking you for your patience with a newbie.

Comment: I believe these might be handled exceptions by the `.add()` function as a part of the ArrayList. It doesn't explain, however, why I am getting repeat values. I have run a test using identical code except printing the result of the `writeResultSet()` method and it claims to have received different values. So for some reason between getting the data from the MySQL table and putting it into ArrayList something goes wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You use Eclipse. This is kind of vague, but from what we know my advices:
Right click on the project in the Project Explorer, then click Properties (bottom of the context menu). In the upcoming Properties dialog's left-side tree-view select "Java Build Path", this is your friend. You can see which Libraries are included, what are the library and project dependencies. You can set the order of export and imports, check what sources are included, etc.

Also you can check the "Java Compiler" tree node in the Properties dialog. You can see and change your Java compatibility level, which JDK provides the JVM for you, other settings which can be important too.

The main cause is that probably the not found classes are not in the classpath. Since it comes from your own source code, check what source folders are included in the dialog I guided you on the ("Source" tab).

Check that your project has the desired layout, the packages are in place. Is this a project you imported from somewhere else?

Comment: I have only imported the mysql-connector project. It appears to be working with my code to the best of my knowledge. But does the mysql-connector project always red-flag with so many errors?

Comment: In my experience that can happen even in case of your own source. If the red flag is on a higher level, then it maybe harmless and you can ignore it. That means some higher level build system related (possible) problems, you may overcome of those in command line. If an actual file is red flagged, then that's a bigger problem, something wrong with the compilation of the particular file, but in that case you usually get some indication on which program lines are the problematic. (In case of build level errors you can look for the red flag opening up the makefiles).

Comment: But let me ask you what make system you use. Maven or ant or something else? How did you exactly add mysql-connector? With Maven you just have to list it as dependency and then everything will be taken care of (in theory).

Comment: Just to clarify: when I say bigger problem, I don't mean that a build system-level problem is good. But sometimes those come from the fact that the Eclipse Maven plugin works differently than when I just work on the command line. I just ignore the trippin' of the Eclipse Maven plugin, I'll build the ear anyway on the commandline in the end. In tat case however you won't be able to use hot deploy and some handy features corresponding to your application server or target (since Eclipse's own build has a problem).

Comment: Well it appears that all of the MySQL stuff has been sorted. The problem still remains, however, that for some reason my `ArrayList<Player>` is still filling with the last player in the scores table four times. Instead of filling with each of the four players in a row.

Comment: Hold on. Then you don't have classnotfound exception any more? You didn't tell this "four times" stuff before. How did you solve the MySqlConnector issue?